# Ways to connect to the network

Tags: home-networking

I have my router setup downstairs and I have a blu ray player upstairs that I want to connect to the network.  I have read about Power over ethernet and have also thought of running a long network cable to the router but are there any other options to connect the blu ray player to my home network?

Comment: You're thinking of powerline networking, not power over ethernet (PoE). They're basically the opposite of each other.

Answer (score 2):

If your downstairs router is also an 802.11 (Wi-Fi) access point, then you could get an adaptor that allows any Ethernet device to get onto a wireless network. But that's not the best choice as network architecture goes. Generally you should use wired network connections for stationary devices, and reserve your wireless bandwidth for laptops and other mobile devices. Long term, running proper Ethernet cable through the walls/floor/ceiling is the best choice.

Comment: While a powerline ethernet will work for most cases, a bluray player will more than likely choke it.  A cable is the best solution.